# Create stringbuilder type functionality in javascript to display chat messages

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, html, asp.net-ajax

dt_msg is a datatable in which I have some chat messages , sent at and sent by.
I bring that messages on screen using stringbuilder like this

```
stringBuilder1.Append("<div style='background-color:ALICEBLUE;float:left; width:100%; word-wrap: break-word;font-size:14px;'><pre><font color='Red'><b><div style='background-color:ALICEBLUE;word-wrap: break-word; margin-right:410px;'>" + dt_msg.Rows[i][2].ToString() + " Says: </b></font></pre></div><div style='background-color:ALICEBLUE;font-size:14px;float: left;width: 410px;margin-left: -410px; word-wrap: break-word;font-size:14px;'><pre><font>" + dt_msg.Rows[i][0].ToString() + "</font></pre></div><div style='background-color:ALICEBLUE; word-wrap: break-word;'><p style='color:#8B8A8A; margin-top:0'>Sent at " + Convert.ToDateTime(dt_msg.Rows[i][1]).ToLongTimeString() + "</p></div><div style='clear:both;'></div>")
```

Now I'm using Ajax with webserices and now messages are returned from webmethod as string like this

```
User1 says :~Hello to this world and enjoy this week~sent at 05:40:30 AM@#User2 says :~Hello to my world~sent at 05:41:35 AM;
```

and it is received in ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSuccess(data) {
       if (data.d)
       {
          div1.innerText = data.d;
       }
           }
  </script>
```

Now div1 shows

```
User1 says :~Hello to this world and enjoy this week~sent at 05:40:30 AM@#User2 says :~Hello to my world~sent at 05:41:35 AM;
```

But I want to display messages like I displayed using stringBuilder in previous page. How can I display the string as I displayed using stringBuilder. Here in the string @# is the row separator

Answer (score 1):

A `StringBuilder` construct is not needed if you create the proper structure for this, use a unordered list (`ul` -> all messages) and continually add list items to it (`li` -> each message)

```
var data = 'User1 says :~Hello to this world and enjoy this week~sent at 05:40:30 AM@#User2 says :~Hello to my world~sent at 05:41:35 AM';

var ul = document.getElementById('your_ul');

data.split('@#').forEach(function(d) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = d;
    ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

<sub>note that the above is untested</sub>

Comment: `User1 says :~Hello to this world and enjoy this week~sent at 05:40:30 AM@#User2 says :~Hello to my world~sent at 05:41:35 AM` How do I display this using javascript in best possible ways

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
div1.innerText = data.d;
```

with

```
div1.innerText = div1.innerText + data.d;
```